# Sharepoint: Programmatic Copy File to Another Document library

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, I would like to automatically copy a file to another site when it is uploaded.

My question is:

1. Is it possible to put into practice?
2. If it is possible,  could this function be created in JavaScript with Script Editor Web Parts?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a very hacky solution if you get it to work. The recommend approach is to use remote event receivers to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks thllbrg and Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: Thanks thllbrg and Sorry for my late reply.
Ah, so that's how it is.  We will  consider Remote event receiver. 
Thanks for your help.